# recursive digit sum of number , Is there a better way to write this functions?

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, ordereddictionary

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

First function returns the recursive digit sum of that number. The second function return dictionary where key is reg_dig_sum and value is count of that number occurring. when I tested it it failed giving me this

`elf.assertEqual(sum_dict[0], 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1`

How can I solve this?

```
def reg_dig_sum(n):
    x = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(n))
    if x < 10:
        return x
    else:
        return reg_dig_sum(x)

def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
    distr = {}
    for x in range(low, high):
        if reg_dig_sum(x) not in distr:
            distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] = 0
        else:
            distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] += 1 
    return distr
```

Comment: From what i understood this line `distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] = 0`  should be `distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] = 1`.

Comment: Thank you I agreed!

Comment: @KateKiatsiri your questions will be more easily answered if you format them properly, like Chris stated above. It really does help; it can be hard for newcomers to the community to get a foothold.

Answer (score 2):

- The problem I can think is your count for each reg_dig_sum will be one less than what it should be. That's the reason assertion condition is failing.
- You can fix this logical error by initializing distr to either `1` or by removing `else` condition.
- I would also suggest to use other alternatives like `defaultdict` to take care of initialization for you.

```
def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
    distr = {}
    for x in range(low, high):
        if reg_dig_sum(x) not in distr:
            distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] = 1 # this should be initialized to 1 for first occurance.
        else:
            distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] += 1 
    return distr
```

- Using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
def distr_of_rec_digit_sums(low=0, high=1500):
    distr = defaultdict(int)
    for x in range(low, high):
        distr[reg_dig_sum(x)] += 1 
    return distr
```

Comment: @Chris Question is already incomplete i provided one line description but without furthur clarification from OP its hard to explain.

Comment: I agree: the question isn't clear. Therefore it's _very_ difficult to provide a useful answer. And it doesn't change the fact that code should be accompanied by an explanation.

Comment: @Chris Updated and explained my current solution

Comment: @Poojan Thanks for helping. My question is I don't know what's wrong with my codes. It's failing the tests. So I changed my code as you suggests however it still failed. Hopeless here

Comment: ok guys I missed read that high is inclusive :( so I j just change for x in range(low, high + 1 ) and it works just fine! Thank you you all!!!!

Answer (score 1):

See previous comments and answers regarding changing 0 to 1

Also try to use much simpler code for reg_dig_sum with the same result:

```
def reg_dig_sum(n):
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1
```

Comment: yes but then I can't use the function reg_dig_sum() within another function to be a key of dictionary..

Comment: I am not sure I understand you question right, but I cannot see any difference for using reg_dig_sum() from other functions or from the global scope - between your code and my code. But my version is much faster and the result is the same. The only difference if you use zero as an argument - then you have to specify result explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I've used a simple function to do this for a long time:

```py
def sum_digits(num):
    if num <= 9:
        return num
    num = int(num / 10) + num - int(num / 10) * 10
    ''' takes the last digit of num off, and adds it to num. '''
    return sum_digits(num)
```

There are a lot of things you can find with this function. Try this on the power series, and you'll see what I mean. Really any mathematical function you could use on a number line will return interesting patterns; this function helps you see part of that.